# Returning a bool value inside Try-Catch block in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, return, try-catch

```
 public bool RemoveProduct(int id)
        {
            // code to remove product by the id provided as parameter
            try 
            {
                var prod = productlist.Where(s => s.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
                productlist.Remove(prod);
            }
            catch (Exception) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            

        }
```

I tried to call the function RemoveProduct(id) with parameter Id which is not present in the productlist, it should return false but it is always returning true no matter what. How to solve this problem and return false when the product with the given id isn't in the list?

Comment: When you step through the code in a debugger, what specifically happens?  What exception are you expecting to be thrown and why?  If the operation is succeeding, what's the problem?  At a glance it looks like you're trying to rely on exceptions for business logic, which is never a good idea.  Under what condition do you want to `return false`?  How can you check for that condition?

Comment: Instead of checking true/false check if prod.Count() > 0.  You do not get an exception when linq returns nothing.

Comment: I mean, I'm not saying that it's good practice, but if OP **really** wanted an exception when finding nothing, he'd juste have to use `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: As @David mentions, the debugger is your friend.  You could have answered this question yourself if you had put a breakpoint on the `return false;` statement and stepped through your code - likely in less time than it took to write up your question.  You want to get used to using the debugger - it is the programmer's best tool

Comment: @Flydog57 Two MSDN pages would have given him the answer (and in retrospect I should have included them in my answer) the breakpoint would just have highlighted what he already knew : no exceptions were thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because neither `FirstOrDefault()` or `Remove()` will throw an exception  when not finding a value in your list.

You could either return false if you didn't find your item (`prod == null`).

Or just return the result of `Remove()` (though if you have a null item and did not find an item with the provided id, you'd end up removing it and returning true either way)

As it is right now, the only case where your method would return false is when your list is null, resulting in a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, if you really want a true/false return.

```
public bool RemoveProduct(int id)
{
    // code to remove product by the id provided as parameter
    var prod = productlist.Where(s => s.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
 
    if (prod == null) return false;        

    productlist.Remove(prod);

    return true;
}
```